# Generalized Poincaré Inequality on H1 proof

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces

let's see if someone can help me with this proof.

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain. And let $L^2\left(\Omega\right)$ be the space of equivalence classes of square integrable functions in $\Omega$ given by the equivalence relation $u\sim v \iff u(x)=v(x)\, \text{a.e.}$ being a.e. almost everywhere, in other words, two functions belong to the same equivalence classes if they only are different in a zero meassure set.

This space is a Hilbert space and its norm is:

$$ \Vert v \Vert ^2_{L^2 \left( \Omega \right) }= \int_\Omega v(x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x $$

Let $H^1\left(\Omega\right)=\left\{ v\in L^2\left( \Omega \right);\,\vert\mathbf{grad}(v)\vert \in L^2\left( \Omega \right ) \right\}$ be also a Hilbert space and its norm :

$$ \Vert v \Vert ^2_{H^1 \left( \Omega \right) }= \Vert v \Vert ^2_{L^2 \left( \Omega \right) } + \Vert \vert\mathbf{grad}(v)\vert \Vert ^2_{L^2 \left( \Omega \right) } $$

I've been asked to proove that:

$$ \Vert v \Vert ^2_{H^1 \left( \Omega \right) } \le C\left( \Omega\right) \left( \Vert \vert\mathbf{grad}(v)\vert \Vert ^2_{L^2 \left( \Omega \right) } + \int_\Gamma \left ( \gamma v(x) \right) ^2\,\mathrm{d}\sigma \right) \quad \forall v\in H^1 \left( \Omega \right) $$

where $\Gamma = \partial \Omega $, $\Omega $ is smooth enough, $\mathrm{d}\sigma$ is a meassure on the boundary of $\Omega$, and the operator $\gamma: L^2\left( \Omega\right )\mapsto L^2\left( \Gamma\right )$ is the trace operator. ( if it is needed I can define it also )

Sincerely, I just don't know how to begin, and maybe someone could give me some clue about it.(by the way the $C$ is a positive constant depending only on the domain $\Omega$).

Thank you very much!

Comment: The trace map is not well defined on $L^2(\Omega)$; you should instead have $\gamma\colon H^1(\Omega) \to L^2(\Gamma)$.

Comment: You have been asked to prove this. You have not been asked to get someone on the internet to prove it for you.

Answer (score 1):

This is (tightly related to) formulae (6.11.2) in Maz'ya's book on *Sobolev spaces*, 2011 edition; or Corollary 1 in §4.11.1 in the 1985 edition.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for the downvote?

Comment: It isn't an answer.

Comment: Huh? Maz'ya proves an assertion that is the OP's inequality in disguise. Isn't this the clue the OP was looking for?